# Grouping array based on the key value similarity

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Let's say I have an array like that:

```
$data[0]['name'] = 'product 1 brandX';
$data[0]['id_product'] = '77777777';
$data[1]['name'] = 'brandX product 1';
$data[1]['id_product'] = '77777777';
$data[2]['name'] = 'brandX product 1 RED';
$data[2]['id_product'] = '77777777';
$data[3]['name'] = 'product 1 brandX';
$data[3]['id_product'] = '';
$data[4]['name'] = 'product 2 brandY';
$data[4]['id_product'] = '8888888';
$data[5]['name'] = 'product 2 brandY RED';
$data[5]['id_product'] = '';
```

I am trying to group them by their similarities (name or id_product).

That would be the expected final array:

```
$uniques[0]['name'] = 'product 1 brandX'; //The smallest name for the product
$uniques[0]['count'] = 4; //Entry which has all the words of the smallest name or the same id_product
$uniques[0]['name'] = 'product 2 brandY';
$uniques[0]['count'] = 2;
```

That's what I tried so far:

```
foreach ($data as $t) {
    if (!isset($uniques[$t['id_product']]['name']) || mb_strlen($uniques[$t['id_product']]['name']) > mb_strlen($t['name'])) {
        $uniques[$t['id_product']]['name'] = $t['name'];
        $uniques[$t['id_product']]['count']++;
    }
}
```

But I can't be based on the id_product because sometimes it will be the same product but one will have the id and the other one no. I have to check the name also, but couldn't manage to get it done.

Comment: Why can have different products the same ID?

Comment: Sorry, I may have explained it wrongly. It's the same product, but they can have different names from one store to another and sometimes their product id can be null. I depend from a third part to get the information and sometimes the information is not complete. Is it clear?

Comment: @Roots did you see my answer bellow I created a working demo [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a69be88f0b79b8c0f8b608f4b0417b9ec26d4d07), click to execute to run demo, Please take a look

Comment: I have voted this question closed as unclear.  I would like to post an answer if you can clarify the question.  Specifically, I'd like to see some "more realistic" sample data, so that we can better understand the data that needs to be processed as "similar".

Comment: What exactly isn't clear for you? I have name and a number for a product, but the stores register them as they want. Some of the time the information is correct and sometimes confuse. I want to group similar products to show them on one page. So, my strategy was to get the smallest names, check if the other names have the same words as the smallest one, in case they have I group them. If not, I check for the id if it's the same or not, if yes I count 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm basing my answer on two assumptions about how products should be grouped:

1. Although `id_product` can be missing, where it is present, it is
   correct and sufficient to match two products; and
2. For two product names to match, the longest `name` (name with the most
   words) must contain all of the words in the shortest `name` (name with
   the fewest words).

Given these assumptions, here is a function to determine if two individual products match (products should be grouped together) and a helper function to get words from names:

```
function productsMatch(array $product1, array $product2)
{
    if (
        !empty($product1['id_product'])
        && !empty($product2['id_product'])
        && $product1['id_product'] === $product2['id_product']
    ) {
        // match based on id_product
        return true;
    }
    $words1 = getWordsFromProduct($product1);
    $words2 = getWordsFromProduct($product2);
    $min_word_count = min(count($words1), count($words2));
    $match_word_count = count(array_intersect_key($words1, $words2));
    if ($min_word_count >= 1 && $match_word_count === $min_word_count) {
        // match based on name similarity
        return true;
    }
    // no match
    return false;
}

function getWordsFromProduct(array $product)
{
    $name = mb_strtolower($product['name']);
    preg_match_all('/\S+/', $name, $matches);
    $words = array_flip($matches[0]);
    return $words;
}
```

This function can be used to group the products:

```
function groupProducts(array $data)
{
    $groups = array();
    foreach ($data as $product1) {
        foreach ($groups as $key => $products) {
            foreach ($products as $product2) {
                if (productsMatch($product1, $product2)) {
                    $groups[$key][] = $product1;
                    continue 3; // foreach ($data as $product1)

                }
            }
        }
        $groups[] = array($product1);
    }
    return $groups;
}
```

And then this function can be used to extract the shortest name and count for each group:

```
function uniqueProducts(array $groups)
{
    $uniques = array();
    foreach ($groups as $products) {
        $shortest_name = '';
        $shortest_length = PHP_INT_MAX;
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $length = mb_strlen($product['name']);
            if ($length < $shortest_length) {
                $shortest_name = $product['name'];
                $shortest_length = $length;
            }
            $count++;
        }
        $uniques[] = array(
            'name' => $shortest_name,
            'count' => $count,
        );
    }
    return $uniques;
}
```

So combining all 4 functions, you can get the uniques as follows (tested with php 5.6):

```
$data[0]['name'] = 'product 1 brandX';
$data[0]['id_product'] = '77777777';
$data[1]['name'] = 'brandX product 1';
$data[1]['id_product'] = '77777777';
$data[2]['name'] = 'brandX product 1 RED';
$data[2]['id_product'] = '77777777';
$data[3]['name'] = 'product 1 brandX';
$data[3]['id_product'] = '';
$data[4]['name'] = 'product 2 brandY';
$data[4]['id_product'] = '8888888';
$data[5]['name'] = 'product 2 brandY RED';
$data[5]['id_product'] = '';

$groups = groupProducts($data);
$uniques = uniqueProducts($groups);
var_dump($uniques);
```

Which gives output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(16) "product 1 brandX"
    ["count"]=>
    int(4)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(16) "product 2 brandY"
    ["count"]=>
    int(2)
  }
}
```

Comment: You are correct about the rules to group the products. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will solve your problem, but it may get you moving forward again

```
    $data = [];

    $data[0]['name']       = 'product 1 brandX';
    $data[0]['id_product'] = '77777777';
    $data[1]['name']       = 'brandX product 1';
    $data[1]['id_product'] = '77777777';
    $data[2]['name']       = 'brandX product 1 RED';
    $data[2]['id_product'] = '77777777';
    $data[3]['name']       = 'product 1 brandX';
    $data[3]['id_product'] = '';
    $data[4]['name']       = 'product 2 brandY';
    $data[4]['id_product'] = '8888888';
    $data[5]['name']       = 'product 2 brandY RED';
    $data[5]['id_product'] = '';

    $data = collect($data);

    $tallies = [
        'brand_x' => 0,
        'brand_y' => 0,
        'other'   => 0
    ];

    $unique = $data->unique(function ($item) use (&$tallies){
        switch(true){
            case(strpos($item['name'], 'brandX') !== false):
                $tallies['brand_x']++;

                return 'product X';
                break;

            case(strpos($item['name'], 'brandY') !== false):
                $tallies['brand_y']++;

                return 'product Y';
                break;

            default:
                $tallies['other']++;

                return 'other';
                break;
        }
    });


    print_r($unique);
    print_r($tallies);
```

Comment: The problem is: it doesn't have only two products. It will be dynamic. I have to find the similarities dynamically and not static.

Comment: And I also have to check if the product id is the same in case the name is not similar, even though they are the same product.

Comment: @Roots Ya, I figured products would all be dynamic.  I think we're both just trying to get simple examples uploaded.  If I were in your shoes, I'd check out collections.  They let you sort, filter, transform, query in ways that arrays just don't.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections

Comment: thanks for your thoughts. I had a look at collection but couldn't figure out also. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve this is to use a unique `product_id`, but if you want create unique keys by finding similarities in the name field you can use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to transform names to arrays and then use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to find an array of difference. 2 names are considered unique if their difference count is lower than 2. I create this function it returns similar names in `$arr` or `false` if not found:

```
function get_similare_key($arr, $name) {

    $names = preg_split("/\s+/", $name); 

    // get similaire key from $arr
    foreach( $arr as $key => $value ) {

        $key_names = preg_split("/\s+/", $key); 
        $diff = array_diff($key_names, $names); 
        if ( count($diff) <= 1 ) { 
            return $key;
        }

    }

    return false;

}
```

Here is a working demo [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a69be88f0b79b8c0f8b608f4b0417b9ec26d4d07)

Comment: How could I consider the same product_id to count +1 as well? Let's say, it checks the name, if the name is not the same, check the product_id.

Comment: But you said that product_id could be diferrent that's why you should base on product name similarities, for example if the program found that 2 name refers to the same product and their Ids are different, what should happens then ?

Comment: The mandatory key is the name, but if it checks and fail.. I want to check the id_product...

Comment: It will only check the id_product if the name isn't the same.